# How to find $5^{2015}\pmod{11} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How do I find this value. It's a very huge number to calculate. I do not know how to start here. Help will be appreciated.
$$5^{2015}\pmod{11} ?$$
Thanks.

Comment: See [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem).

Comment: @Lucian so answer is 5 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fermat's Little Theorem says that $5^{11}\equiv 5\mod{11}$.  Or in other words, $5^{10}\equiv1\mod{11}$.
Now $5^{2015}=(5^{10})^{201}5^5$.

Answer (score 3):

Without invoking little Fermat one has $5^2=25\equiv 3\pmod{11}$ which gives $5^4\equiv 9\pmod{11}$. Multiplying by $5$ we have $5^5\equiv 45\equiv 1\pmod{11}$. And $5^{2015}=(5^5)^{403}\equiv 1\pmod{11}$

Answer (score 1):

$5^{2015}=5^{(5\cdot403)}=(5^5)^{403}=3125^{403}$

$3125\equiv1\pmod{11}\implies3125^{403}\equiv1\pmod{11}$

Answer (score 1):

$$5^3=125\equiv4\pmod{11}\implies5^5\equiv5^2\cdot4\equiv1$$

$\implies5^{2015}=(5^5)^{403}\equiv1^{403}\pmod{11}$

Answer (score 1):

${\rm mod}\ 11\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{5\equiv 4^{\large 2}}\,\Rightarrow\, 5^{\large\rm 5N}\equiv (\color{#c00}4^{\large\color{#c00}2\cdot 5})^{\large\rm N}\equiv 1^{\large\rm N}\equiv 1\,$ by little Fermat

Answer (score 0):

It is not a huge number to calculate.  In `Mathematica`:

```
Mod[5^2015 , 11]
```

(* 1 *)

takes 0.00038 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

By euler fermat equation you can do it in general $5^{\phi(11)} = 1 (mod 11)$

Hence $5^{10} = 1(mod 11)$ so we have $5^{2015} = 5^5 mod 11$.

Comment: @godonichia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function